# With autotools how do I get pandoc to run in the src dir next to c programs

Tags: pandoc, autotools

I am creating a c program where I use a `design.md` document inside the src directory so the design is close to the source code. I use autotools, but I do not know how to get `automake` to run `pandoc` next to the c compiler. This is my `Makefile.am`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = brun
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c11
AM_LDFLAGS = -rdynamic
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libbrun.la
libbrun_la_SOURCES = Object.c Box.c Module.c
libbrun_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 0:0:0
brun_SOURCES = main.c
brun_LDADD = libbrun.la
include_HEADERS = Object.h Object.r.h Box.h Box.r.h Module.h Module.r.h
# EXTRA_DIST = Object.r Box.r Module.r
#
%.pdf: %.md
    pandoc -o $@ $<
```

The above code does nothing to generate my files `design.md` and `todo.md` which are in the `src` directory.

I have searched for clues how to do this but most results point to how to use autotools for compiling or just contain general tutorials. I have been searching for a day or so and my have become blind to the obvious.

Does anyone know how to get automake to run pandoc, next to compiling my c sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided a `make` rule that describes *how* to build PDFs from your `.md` files, but your `Makefile.am` doesn't anywhere express that any PDF files actually should be built, much less which ones.

For files that you want to have *installed* (and why are you building docs if you don't want to install them) the specifics depend on where you want them to go, but for example,

```
pkgdata_DATA = design.pdf todo.pdf
```

That would build them as part of `make all` and install them to a subdirectory of `$(datadir)` during `make install` (probably something like `/usr/local/share/brun`).

If for some reason you want the files built, but *not* installed, then you could instead use

```
noinst_DATA = design.pdf todo.pdf
```

Either way, since you're relying on a suffix rule for unusual suffixes, you'll probably also have to tell Automake about them:

```
SUFFIXES = .md .pdf
```

Note well that `make` recognizes a similar construct, but you should not use `make`'s variation in Automake; instead, use the above variable-assignment form, and Automake will handle converting that for `make`'s use.

Comment: Thank your very much, this is what I needed. Just to be sure I understand this right. Your last remark refers to the %.pdf rule, is that right? If that is what you mean, how I can tell automake.am the "automake" way that I want to use pandoc?

Comment: No, @guus, not exactly.  I meant that you should use the `SUFFIXES = .md .pdf` line I showed as opposed to `.SUFFIXES: .md .pdf`.  The latter is the similar construct recognized by `make`.

Comment: But while we're on that topic, @guus, I do also suggest changing "`%.pdf: %.md`" to "`.pdf.md:`".  The former is specific to GNU `make`, and is not supported by most other `make` implementations.  In general, GNU recommends the former, which does have advantages, but one of the points of the Autotools is to be adaptable to the local tools, including `make`, even when they are not GNU. Employing GNUisms conflicts with that.

Comment: I marked your answer as solution and +1 because of complete answer. I did indeed get a warning for the GNUism. Now I know how to adapt that. Thanks!